# Finding all objects with a certain field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My mapping looks like so:

```
"condition": {
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "value": {
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
},
```

and some data I have looks like:

```
"condition": [
    {
        "name": "condition",
        "value": "new",
    },
    {
        "name": "condition",
        "value": "gently-used",
    }
]
```

How can I write a query that finds all objects within the array that have a `new` condition?
I have the following but I am getting 0 results back:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "attribute_condition": "new"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to map your `condition` field as a [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).

```
"condition": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "name": { "type": "keyword" },
        "value": { "type": "keyword" }
    }
},
```

Now you're able to query each element of the `condition` array independently from each other. Next, you need to use the [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) and request to [retrieve the inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) and output them in the `inner_hits` object of the query response

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "condition",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "condition.value": "new"
            }
          },
          "inner_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An example response will look like below:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.6931471,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "nested",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Xx_LN3gBp5RUqdfAef3B",
        "_score" : 0.6931471,
        "_source" : {
          "condition" : [
            {
              "name" : "condition",
              "value" : "new"
            },
            {
              "name" : "condition",
              "value" : "gently-used"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {     <--- here begins the list of inner hits
          "condition" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 0.6931471,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "nested",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "Xx_LN3gBp5RUqdfAef3B",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "condition",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 0.6931471,
                  "_source" : {
                    "name" : "condition",
                    "value" : "new"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without changing the mapping? This isn't an option for me, as the "condition" property is a dynamically created object

Comment: Have you tried this? `{ "query": { "match": { "condition.value": "new" } } }`